# selenium IDE... write output to external file

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

how to write the output to external file in Selenium IDE. I tried file logging add on but it printing complete log of test case to csv file
I want to print output of test case to external file in selenium IDE

please help me...

Comment: When you say "output" did you mean Test result?

Comment: yes i want specific test result

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried "[Test results (Selenium IDE)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/test-results-selenium-ide/)"? I've not used it myself but it looks like the sort of thing that may help you

Answer (score 0):

Test results is quite limited if you want to analyse the test data. If you are data-driven and need to run analytics later, what you can do is capture the result of your commands as variables and type them into a database with a web front end.

I use this method to do analytics on my test data.

Good luck.